# Cassandra CQL wildcard search

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a table structure like

**create table file(id text primary key, fname text, mimetype text, isdir boolean, location text); 

create index file_location on file (location);**

and following is the content in the table:

**insert into file (id, fname, mimetype, isdir, location) values('1', 'f1', 'pdf', False, 'c:/test/');

insert into file (id, fname, mimetype, isdir, location) values('2', 'f2', 'pdf', False, 'c:/test/');

insert into file (id, fname, mimetype, isdir, location) values('3', 'f3', 'pdf', False, 'c:/test/');

insert into file (id, fname, mimetype, isdir, location) values('4', 'f4', 'pdf', False, 'c:/test/a/');**

I want to list out all the ids matching the following criteria:

**select id from file where location like '%/test/%';**

I know that like is not supported in CQL, can anyone please suggest the approach should I take for these kind of wildcard search queries. Please suggest.

Answer (score 7):

DataStax Enterprise adds full text search to Cassandra: http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/search_index

Comment: Is there an alternative to DataStax. It doesn't seem to have a version for windows. I am mainly looking for DSE Search.

Answer (score 1):

As of Cassandra 3.4, this is possible with SASI indexes. This should work:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX string_search_idx ON file(location) 
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'mode': 'CONTAINS',
    'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer',
    'tokenization_enable_stemming': 'true',
    'tokenization_locale': 'en',
    'tokenization_skip_stop_words': 'true',
    'analyzed': 'true',
    'tokenization_normalize_lowercase': 'true'
};
```

This shall search for all "%abc%" queries on the column "file".
More information [here](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058).

Comment: Please note, that SASI indexes are almost unmaintained, so in C* 4.0 they will be disabled by default, and to enable them you'll need to change `cassandra.yaml`...