# Use wildcard to filter URL in AppDynamics

Tags: appdynamics

I'm trying to filter on AppDynamics to get all the request to a particular REST URL, the REST URL is not fixed as long as in the URL

/AppEngine/rest/evac/${id}/createNewActivity

On the Transaction Snapshots you have the option to filter results, and in the filters you can filter by URL:

[image: Filters on AppDynamics]

If I search for a concrete URL (with ${id} defined) I can search it, but I cannot find how to use a wildcar to find this URL with any ${id}. I tried so far to use

- /AppEngine/rest/evac/*/createNewActivity
- /AppEngine/rest/evac/.*/createNewActivity

With no results.

The one with works just a bit is using /AppEngine/rest/evac/* which also retrieves other REST which start with the same URL, so I can export the results and filter outside AppDynamics.

But there is a way to use a wildcard so I can find the desired results in AppDynamics?

Comment: Have you tried searching by a keyword "createNewActivity"?

Comment: Yes, in this case works (you can see in my own answer) but still wildcar could be useful for another searches.

Comment: I didn't noticed ;-). Have you tried SQL wildcards?.

Comment: @wadjakman Thanks for suggestion, it's still not working. Having in mind AppDynamics stores data in a Cassandra DB seems like it would be not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444567/cassandra-cql-wildcard-search http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/support-for-wildcard-search-in-cassandra :(

Answer (score 0):

Even it is not the desired behaviour, if filtering by URL and specifying only createNewActivity worked for me (as long as there are no other REST URLs matching this).